# placing an element on the bottom of a container with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to place a red element 100px height on the bottom of a container with CSS. I've tried this but the red element is not showing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```css
.banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}

.element {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="banner">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Searching for similar threads, I've also tried to change the positioning method but I can't make it work. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You might have a height of 100, but the width is 0.  Add  width: 100%; to your style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` to class `element`, then you will see a full width `<div>`

```css
.banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}

.element {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="banner">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a width as well:

```
.element{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom:0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}

.element {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
</section>
```

Otherwise, it's just a one-dimensional div and you won't be able to see it.

Comment: Thank you so much! is there any way to set the width of the element to the one of its container? that was the reason I hadn't specified it before

Comment: No problem. If you set the parent div's width, you can then set ```.element```'s width to ```inherit``` and it will be the same width as ```.banner```

Answer (score 0):

You code is OK, and The `div` is empty and nothing displayed in page.
You can contain some elements inside the `div`, or define its width.

Please check below codes.

```html
<style>
.banner{

  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}

.element{
  background-color: red;
  Width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="banner">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

```
.element {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000000000000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.banner {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
}
```